# How to get the Display Size in Inches in Android?

Tags: android

I need for my Application the exact inch of a display. My current solution is:

```
double inch;
double x = Math.pow(widthPix/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(heigthPix/dm.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);

inch = screenInches;

inch = inch * 10;
inch = Math.round(inch);
inch = inch / 10;
```

Is there a better way to get the display inch? Current on my test device 4 inch it say 5.9 and that is wrong...

Comment: Seems to be the best you can do. If the device lies about its metrics we don't have a chance.

Comment: hm ok. Is there a list of device that "lie"?

Comment: I don't know of any list. Another idea would be to give the user a possibility to override.

Answer (score 8):

The following gave me a a result quite close to the specs:

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    double density = dm.density * 160;
    double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / density, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / density, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
    log.info("inches: {}", screenInches);
```

Output: `inches: 4.589389937671455`
Specs: Samsung Galaxy Nexus (720 x 1280 px, ~320 dpi, 4.65")

Please note, that `dm.heightPixels` (or `dm.widthPixels` depending on your orientatation) does not necessarily provide accurate information, since soft keys (as used in the Galaxy Nexus) are not added to the height (or width).

Comment: double density = dm.density * 160; what is 160?

Comment: That is the reference density of a mdpi-screen where 1 dp = 1 px. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density

Comment: While using this calculation I should get 5.5 for Google Pixel XL, but I am getting 4.9

Answer (score 6):

Try this.... This will give you the exact size of the display..

```
static String getDisplaySize(Activity activity) {
    double x = 0, y = 0;
    int mWidthPixels, mHeightPixels;
    try {
        WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        Point realSize = new Point();
        Display.class.getMethod("getRealSize", Point.class).invoke(display, realSize);
        mWidthPixels = realSize.x;
        mHeightPixels = realSize.y;
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        x = Math.pow(mWidthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
        y = Math.pow(mHeightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", Math.sqrt(x + y));
}
```