# Hide keyboard if screen size is 5.0"

Tags: android

I want to hide soft Keyboard if the device is 5.0" or lower programatically.

```
 int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
    switch (screenSize) {
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }
```

I've tried with the below code but this will not give me the device size. is there any way i can get the device size?

Comment: you can get display size it's hard to get mobile size

Comment: @Ashish I guess he meant display size only not the actual physical dimension of the device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Display Size in Inches in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445050/how-to-get-the-display-size-in-inches-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a lot of ways to get the display size. I think you want display size in `Inch`. So you can take a look at the snippet of code. Hope it will help you.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int widthSize = dm.widthPixels;
int heightSize = dm.heightPixels;
double wi = (double) widthSize / (double) dm.xdpi;
double hi = (double) heightSize / (double) dm.ydpi;
double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
double screenSizeInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
```

You will get the actual screen size in `screenSizeInches`. Now you can apply your logic to achieve your actual goal.

Answer (score 0):

you can support in your activities another layout which screen size you need (layout-sw480dp) and in try this to stop showing the keyboard in editText

```
 <EditText
  ...
android:inputType="none"/>
```